# How to add a default loading bar to all global state changes in react-router (redux)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

So, in my react/redux application, I use [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux). I want to add a simple "top-bar" loading animation for any route (eg `LOCATION_CHANGE`) sequences.

I am aware of things like [react-redux-loading-bar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux-loading-bar), but am unsure how to tie them into `react-router-redux`, because I simply import a reducer pre-made, like:

```
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'
```

How can I tie loading animations into this reducer, and does any solution exist ready to go out of the box? Seems like a common use case. I would rather not have to create another reducer that listens for `react-router-redux` actions, that seems a bit hacky...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reviewed [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) documentation and I see two possible implementations:

## 1. Simply listen to the enhanced history via `history.listen`

From the docs:

> [How do I watch for navigation events](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#how-do-i-watch-for-navigation-events-such-as-for-analytics), such as for analytics?
>
> Simply listen to the enhanced history via history.listen. This takes
>   in a function that will receive a location any time the store updates.
>   This includes any time travel activity performed on the store.

Here you can skip creating a new reducer and just create a Loader component. In the component's `componentDidMount` you can subscribe the component to the router history changes and handle all changes internally in the component. Here is the subscribe function:

```
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);
history.listen(location => { // handle showing/hiding loader here });
```

## 2. Create a specific reducer, that listens for [LOCATION_CHANGE](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#location_change) action type and updates its flag

From the docs:

> **LOCATION_CHANGE**: An action type that you can listen for in your reducers to be notified of route updates. Fires after any changes to history.

In that case you have to create a Loader component that's subscribed to the reducer's flag. There you can show the loading indicator. You can hide it after some milliseconds with dispatching a new action, that resets the reducer's flag.

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a detailed response. If the browser history API is how the docs suggest responding to navigation events, I guess that's the way I'll do it. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! :) If you have any additional questions - feel free to ask. Also if the answer helped you - you can mark it as accepted! Thanks! :)